# setting home (default) page in a directory

Tags: php, html, fedora

It's been a while since I created a new directory on my domain (call it my/domain/dir3). I have others, each containing a index.php (dir1/index.php - dir2/index.php), each index is  called if the directory URL is called (thus a URL of my/domain/dir1 will call my/domain/dir1.index.php).

No the embarrasing part ... I've completely forgotten how I did this! ... blank .... nothing ... no recollection. Please somebody enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Apache, it does this automatically. You can tweak the settings in httpd.conf though.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it's a standard Apache/PHP installation then  putting an index.php file in the directory would make it the default page in a directory.

Oh, if you want a different file to be the index. Create a .htaccess file in the directory and enter this:

DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php something.php

Replace something.php with the file you want and presto ;). You can't have two indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If `index.php` is [seen by Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html) as the default index file, `my/domain/dir1/` will see `my/domain/dir1/index.php`. If you want something more complex, You'll need [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).